# Add FormGroup at Component level in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a component with a template like this:

```
<td>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Date: jour/mois/année" formControlName="dateDebut" >
</td>
<td>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Date: jour/mois/année" formControlName="dateFin">
</td>
```

As you might have guessed, the component will be applied (`selector: '[app-xxx]'`) on `tr` elements.

I need (and want) `[formGroup]` to be applied at this component level. How can it be done?

I tried (I'm new at this) the following withouth success:

```
  @HostBinding('[formGroup]') formGroup: FormGroup;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

**child.ts**

```
@Input() form: FormGroup;
```

template:

```
<td [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Date: jour/mois/année" formControlName="dateDebut" >
</td>
<td [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Date: jour/mois/année" formControlName="dateFin">
</td>
```

or like this

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  // content
</div>
```

**parent**

```
<child-selector [form]="parentFormGroup"></child-selector>
```

Comment: Then I'll have to add formgroup directive everywhere, I'd like to avoid that by making the whole component bound to a formGroup.

Comment: like i said, just bound whole component in a tag, then bind directive only once